# Figured out that my .json file needs to be in the public folder (create-react-app) . Is that correct?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Took me  4 hours but why is it that the .json file that I want to access by a components .js file in my src folder needs to be in the public folder? Isn't the src folder already "public" as in everyone can see my code? Thank You for the time.

Comment: You can access json files in src. Which component is trying to use it and where is that component? Make sure the path to the json file is correct. Same folder: `'./myjson'`.

Comment: My component .js file is inside my component folder which is inside the src folder.   If i add my ProductInformation.json file into my component folder I will get this error.  _Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected token < in JSON at position 4_
**  Here is my code `fetchData()
{

  let data = fetch('./ProductInformation.json')
  .then((resp) =>
  {resp.json().then((res) =>{
         console.log(res.Bumper);
    })
  })
}`

Comment: For learning purposes, does it matter where I store my .json file?

Comment: It shouldn't. I have my json file in `src/component/custom_folder/myjson.json`. Can you check if there is a `<` in your json file? Also, why not just `import` the json file?

Comment: I just wanted to try fetch and how it worked. Is there a difference? Why would someone use fetch rather than just import the .json file?

Comment: As far as I know, fetch is typically used for network calls. So there is a delay, such as when I fetch from a rest API today's weather, etc. `import` is immediate, in the sense that you can use the variables you import immediately. Checkout : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: Got it. I have one last question. I am using create-react-app for now, in the future; obviously a website won't be deployed using my local server and create-react-app.  Is it a good idea to keep working on my components in create-react-app? I essentially want to know after I finish a project in create-react-app, how do I "deploy" it to the public?

Comment: You will likely continue to develop your website on your local. You can run `npm build` or if you use yarn then `yarn build`. Then your webpage will be generated in your `build` folder. For me, I host my site over on AWS's S3 bucket. All I need to do is to upload the entire content of my build folder into the bucket, with the `index.html` as the root.

Comment: Got it thank you. How it looks right now in my chrome browser will probably be how other view it aswell, right?

Comment: Also I get it now. You need a fetch() rather than an import if the data changes by the minute right? Like stock markets and weather like you said. If you wanted to change data yourself maybe once a week, you can simply use import.